# notepad++: Space confusion

Tags: notepad++

When I try to align stuff in notepad that was previous align, it gets out of alignment because spaces are not spaces.

e.g., if I have

```
a    b    c
```

and I try to move everything over I might end up with something like

```
a    b      c
```

or

```
a   b  c
```

instead of

```
a    b    c
```

Is there any way to fix this? The name of this "feature", etc?

Comment: `The name of this "feature", etc?` Probably _tab_?

Comment: ***because spaces are not spaces.*** .....whaaaaat?

Comment: If you move the cursor, character by character, over such a big gap, does it make a jump? Then you most definitely have a *tab* character and not a single space.

Comment: In developing it's common practice to us a single space between items on a single line, and to **format** your code with **tabs**

Comment: @Zak Spaces are equally common, and they (spaces) might actually be [more valuable](https://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2017/06/according-to-statistics-programming-with-spaces-instead-of-tabs-makes-you-rich/)... :)

Comment: ^^ @Someprogrammerdude touché!  ...  ... .. I am still laughing!

Comment: Use the Notepad++ menu => **View** => **Show symbol** and select **Show white space and TAB**.

Comment: You can also have Notepad++ replace spaces for tabs (I believe this will apply to new tab entries, not for ones that may already exist). Go to **Settings => Preferences**, click '**Language**' in the left list, and the option to **Replace by space** checkbox will be at the bottom of the far right column.